# Query DbRef in Spring data repository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have two models:

```
@Document('note')
public class Note {
  //fields...
    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    private List<Label> labels = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Document('label')
public class Label {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private String name;
}
```

I've tried this query but it doesn't work:

```
@Query(value = "{ 'labels.$id': ?0) }", fields = "{'_id': 1}")
```

> Slice findNotesByLabelName(String id, Pageable pageable);

How can I query all Notes by Label id?